# How to delete previous List contents and add new contents?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a list that contain 10 images and name. On clicking next button its showing 10 images with name, but its showing previous 10 images also (total 20 images).

I want to display only the present 10 images and want to delete the previous 10 images from the ListView. How can i do this?

I have tried `myArrayList.clear();` `arrayList.remove();`, `adapter.clearListView();` and `listView.removeAllView();` but still i am getting 20 images (10 present images and 10 previous image).

Please suggest some solution with sample code.

My code is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view;  
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();  

  if(convertView==null)  
   {  
       view = new ViewHolder();  
       convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_view, null);
       view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
       view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
       convertView.setTag(view);  
    }  
  else  
    {  

      view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }  

       listImage.clear();
       listText.clear();
       notifySetDataChange();
  return convertView;  
}
```

and i am creating list view in another class and calling adapter in above code..

i have tried to clearing listView also..

Images and names are from server and they are dynamic in nature..

Comment: how you add the images in your array? do you have database from where you getting the images or something else?

Comment: getting images from server..

Comment: do you maintain that only 10 images will store in array getting from the server  on next click? I just want to confirm.

Comment: i will get only 10 images at a time from server on next button..

Comment: try recreate your list and adapter after every click action.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal only with adapter. Reset data in adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

UDP:

getView() is invoked by system every time it needs a view for row. So, don't change a list with data and call notifyDataSetChanged() in this method.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<YourItem> items;

    public void setItems(List<YourItem> newItems) {
        items = newItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(View convertView, int position, ...) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            // your code
        } else {
            // your code
        }

        YourItem item = items.get(position);

        // set image to convertView

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So, call setData() with your new items every time you want to update a ListView.

Are there any more questions?

Comment: how to reset the adapter and where to reste the adapter data? i have cleared the data of arrayList, listView and call'd adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but still its displaying the same 20 images..

Comment: items - your ArrayList with images in adapter. Call items.clear() and notifyDataSetChanged() inside of adapter. If you print the code of your adapter I tell you more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You cant clear list data in getView method. You have to clear from listAdapter. Then it will work correctly.

Comment: if you didn't get it please submit your `list.setAdapter` code. I will try to help you.

Comment: MY CODE IS :   myAdapter = new MylistAdapter(this,listText, listImage);  
      myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         // Set custom adapter to list view  
      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);  
      listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
         listView.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

Comment: may I know what are you doing in `MylistAdapter()`. If you adding those `listText` and `listImage` to a `arrayList` or any `list` from collection means then easily you can clear the list by using `arrayList.clear()` method. You have to clear the list while you are moving to next. That is it. enjoy.

Comment: Please C the above Question for for MylistAdapter() functionality.. ya i have cleared the listText and listImage before going to next page.. but still list have more then 10 elements(20 on next and 30 if we again press next)..

Comment: where you provide ` MylistAdapter() ` functionality.

Comment: MylistAdapter() is a class and the above getView() is within the class MylistAdapter()...